# cluster Analysis, Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent

Tags: r, arrays

I'm trying to use the poLCA package for Latent Clustering Analaysis.

My data frame can be downloaded here as an rda file and saved it into your working directory:
   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eGJprHaXdoVhKNlGD5VcsoND7iyIoNwJ

```
load(file = "QuestionData.rda")
```

When I try to run the LCA :

```
library("MPsychoR")
library("poLCA")
formula <- cbind(Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4) ~ 1
OneClass <- poLCA(formula, data = Output, nclass = 1, nrep = 3)
TwoClass <- poLCA(formula, data = Output, nclass = 2, nrep = 3)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

From reading around and looking at others who've encountered this error, it seems to arise because there is a difference between the number of columns in their data frame and the number of column names they entered into a function... but I have 4 columns in my data frame and 4 added into the poLCA function. Can anyone help me to understand why I'm encountering this error?

If you're not wanting to download my data, the general structure of my data frame is as follows:

```
Question1 <- c('Sufficient', 'Problematic', 'Problematic', 'Sufficient', 
'Excellent')
Question2 <- c('Insufficient', 'Insufficient', 'Insufficient', 'Sufficient', 
'Sufficient')
Question3 <- c('Sufficient', 'Sufficient', 'Insufficient', 'Sufficient', 
'Sufficient')
Question4 <- c('Problematic', 'Insufficient', 'Problematic', 'Problematic', 
'Excellent')
Question5 <- c('Insufficient', 'Sufficient', 'Sufficient', 'Exceptional', 
'Exceptional')

DF <- data.frame(Participants, Question1, Question2, Question3, Question4, 
Question5)

DF$Question1 <- factor(DF$Question1, levels = c("Problematic", 
"Insufficient", "Sufficient", "Excellent"), ordered=TRUE)
DF$Question2 <- factor(DF$Question2, levels = c("Problematic", 
"Insufficient", "Sufficient", "Excellent"), ordered=TRUE)
DF$Question3 <- factor(DF$Question3, levels = c("Problematic", 
"Insufficient", "Sufficient", "Excellent"), ordered=TRUE)
DF$Question4 <- factor(DF$Question4, levels = c("Problematic", 
"Insufficient", "Sufficient", "Excellent"), ordered=TRUE)
DF$Question5 <- factor(DF$Question5, levels = c("Problematic", 
"Insufficient", "Sufficient", "Excellent", "Exceptional"), ordered=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have different levels for each your response variables:

```
summary(Output)
        Question1          Question2          Question3           Question4  
 Problematic :150   Problematic : 57   Problematic :181   Problematic  :456  
 Insufficient:211   Insufficient:157   Insufficient:320   Insufficient :130  
 Sufficient  :238   Sufficient  :692   Sufficient  :405   Sufficient   : 48  
 Excellent   :307   Excellent   :  0                      Excellent    :272  
                                                          ExcellentPlus:  0
```

If I am not wrong (not so familiar with your data), you can have them with the same levels:

```
NewOutput = Output
for(i in 1:ncol(NewOutput)){
    NewOutput[,i] = factor(as.character(Output[,i]),order=TRUE,
    levels=c("Problematic","Insufficient","Sufficient","Excellent"))
}
poLCA(cbind(Question1,Question2,Question3,Question4)~1,data=NewOutput,nclass=1)
```

I omitted "ExcellentPlus" from your factors as it is not found in your example data.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. This gets me most of the way there, using the poLCA now works. However, I want to retain the variables as ordered factors and when I run the line NewOutput = data.frame(NewOutput), they are stored in the data fame as factors with no order to the levels

Comment: When I convert them back to ordered factors using NewOutput$Question1<- ordered(NewOutput$Question1, levels = c("Problematic", "Insufficient", "Sufficient", "Excellent")), then use the poLCA function, I get the same original error

Comment: I have now worked out what the problem was. The error was arising because some factor levels were unused as you highlighted 'StupidWolf'. Simply removing the levels that were not used (including "Excellent" for Question2, helped to overcome the error)

Comment: Hi @interestedindata, you are right it became a character, thanks for pointing out my mistake. The sapply forced it back to a character. See updated answer above to keep it as a factor

Comment: Removing the levels that were not used might work, just check that you get the same solution as when you used a dataframe with same levels for all.